# Does $\Lambda^2_{+}$ generate a differential ideal for a self-dual $4$-manifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, gauge-theory

Let $(X, g)$ be a smooth, oriented, Riemannian 4-diemnsional manifold. Let $\Lambda^2$ denote the bundle of 2-forms on $X$. Then the Hodge-star operator decomposes $\Lambda^2$ into the space of self-dual and anti-self-dual 2-forms
$$\Lambda^2 = \Lambda^2_+ \oplus \Lambda^2_- .$$
Both $\Lambda^2_+$ and $\Lambda^2_-$ are $3$-dimensional bundles.

The Riemannian curvature tensor could be considered as a map $\mathcal{R}: \Lambda^2\to \Lambda^2$ and under the decomposition $\Lambda^2 = \Lambda^2_+ \oplus \Lambda^2_- $, $\mathcal{R}$ could be decomposed as
$$
\mathcal{R}=\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\
B^*&C\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The Riemannian manifold $(X, g)$ is called *self-dual* if we have
$$
C-\frac{1}{3}tr(C)=0.
$$

> > My question is: if $(X, g)$ is self-dual, then do we have
> >     $$
> > d(\Lambda^2_+)\subset \Lambda^2_+\cdot \Lambda^1?
> > $$

Comment: It seems that the answer is yes by trivial reason: $\Lambda^2_+\cdot \Lambda^1$ is the whole $\Lambda^3$.